# How does the statement "public typealias AnyObject" make AnyObject a protocol?

Tags: ios, swift

When I pressed <kbd>Command</kbd> and clicked `AnyObject` to navigate to the interface of the `AnyObject`, I came across the below definition:

```
public typealias AnyObject
```

I see this comment written above the definition:

> The protocol to which all classes implicitly conform.

Well I don't understand how this definition makes `AnyObject` a `protocol` without explicitly using the keyword `protocol`.
Also, it's a `typealias` without `= someType`, which is an invalid statement.

I can't write a statement like:

```
public typealias SomeOtherObject
```

It gives a compilation error.

Can anyone explain what exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that by pressing on `AnyObject` holding `CMD` you will not actually see source code, but just a `public` interface. If you will go deep into Swift source code you will actually find out that

`public typealias AnyObject`

is actually looks like this:

`public typealias AnyObject = Builtin.AnyObject`

Here is the link to file containing this code https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Policy.swift

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: But still why is it not showing error on writing "public typealias AnyObject"?

Comment: @NoProb it shows if code is written this way, but it's not. The code you see is pseudo statement supposed to expose public part of the source. You can play around with it by navigating via cmnd+cntrl+up in your classes and see how it works.